# Error 404 in mvc asp.net. View not display

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes

Im having trouble creating a view and its own actionresult. The error that I get is this one

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
>
> No se encuentra el recurso.
>
> Descripción: HTTP 404. El recurso que está buscando (o una de sus
>   dependencias) se puede haber quitado, haber cambiado de nombre o no
>   estar disponible temporalmente. Revise la dirección URL siguiente y
>   asegúrese de que está escrita correctamente.
>
> Dirección URL solicitada: /Cursos/AgregarAlumno/2

This is my view (I know its unfinished, but I think thats not the problem)

```
@model LibreriaEntidad.Cursos
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AgregarAlumnos";
}

<h2>AgregarAlumnos</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cursos</legend>

        @*<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idCurso)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idCurso)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idCurso)
        </div>*@

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idReparticion)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idReparticion)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idReparticion)
        </div>

        @*<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Presencual)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Presencual)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Presencual)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Virtual)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Virtual)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Virtual)
        </div>*@

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("idUsuario", ViewBag.Usuarios as SelectList)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
</fieldset>
```

and my controller action over here.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AgregarAlumnos(int id = 0)
{
    Cursos cursos = db.Cursos.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Usuarios = new SelectList(db.Usuario, "idUsuario", "Nombre");
    return View(cursos);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're trying `/Cursos/AgregarAlumno` but the name of your action is `AgregarAlumnos` (with an 's'). Also, are you accessing it using POST or GET?

Comment: I changed the name and add the 's' but the error dint leave. Its a post method.

Comment: Is the controller in any 'Area'?

Comment: no it istn in any area

Comment: Your POST method makes no sense. Your view has `@model Cursos` which means you POST method needs to be `public ActionResult AgregarAlumnos(Cursos model)` because thats what your posting back (you not posting an input with `name=id`). And edit you question to show the error message in English!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove **[HttpPost]** attributes from your action.

**Update:**

To display view the action must accept the GET request. You should use two different actions for displaying view and submitting form.

Comment: any explanation why? I just kinda copy it from the edit action, cause its kind the same

Comment: because to display the view, the action result must be a GET. Use post when you are submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need a corresponding `HttpGet` method, as your current one only accepts a `HttpPost` request. Add the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AgregarAlumnos(int id = 0)
{
    Cursos cursos = db.Cursos.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Usuarios = new SelectList(db.Usuario, "idUsuario", "Nombre");
    return View(cursos);
}
```

**HttpGet:-** Whenever any View loads first time `HttpGet` method executes. That means on first request for any URL in Asp.Net MVC `HttpGet` method executes. That means if any URL receives the input through URL we can handle the input through `HttpGet` method.

**HttpPost:-** `HttpPost` method executes once you click on Submit button in MVC form. That means we can process the form data by using `HttpPost` method.